# Build a nested array from a menu in database

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following output from the database and I want to build a menu with this data.

```
$output = [
    ['id_struct' => 1, 'title' => 'A', 'parent' => 0],
    ['id_struct' => 2, 'title' => 'B', 'parent' => 0],
    ['id_struct' => 3, 'title' => 'B1', 'parent' => 2],
    ['id_struct' => 4, 'title' => 'B2', 'parent' => 3],
    ['id_struct' => 5, 'title' => 'C', 'parent' => 0],
];
```

With this output I need to build another array like this:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'title' => string 'A' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'B' (length=1)
      'children' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              'title' => string 'B1' (length=2)
              'children' => 
                array (size=1)
                  0 => 
                    array (size=1)
                      'title' => string 'BB1' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'title' => string 'C' (length=1)
```

It needs to be this format so I can export to JSON.

What is the best way to achieve this? I've found many solutions but all of them are to export the menu to html using print/echo and that will not work here.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too

Comment: Loop and store the values in array depending on `parent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {

$branch = array();

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    if ($element['parent'] == $parentId) {
        $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id_struct']);
        if ($children) {
            $element['children'] = $children;
        }
        $branch[] = $element;
    }
}

 return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($output);
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $tree );
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!